# vba dynamic vlookup range

Tags: vba, excel

I want to make my vlookup range dynamic, so I am using a variable **col** but all I am getting is #N/A in the result column.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

path3 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please browse Output tab excel file")
Set wbs3 = Workbooks.Open(path3)

Set aCell1 = wbs3.Sheets("Output").Range("A1:X1").Find(What:="Functions", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
col = aCell1.Column

lastrow1 = wbs3.Sheets("Analysis").Columns("A").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
With wbs3.Sheets("Analysis").Range("I2:I" & lastrow1)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,'Output'!col:col,1,0)"
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting `col` in the formula means nothing to it as the formula won't resolve what col means. instead you could use string concatenation to resolve the text.

```
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,'Output'!col:col,1,0)"
```

becomes

```
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(H2,'Output'!" & col.address & ",1,0)"
```